# Do I need Microsoft account to connect to Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-account

I have been invited to a project on Visual Studio Team Services. The email address I have been given access to is my work iD like john.smith@work.com

- When I click on project URL. I get to Login with Microsoft account page.
- If I try login with my work ID/pass, ofc it is not recognized by Microsoft
- If i login with my personal MS account, then this account doesn't have access to project hence I get error

What's the way to actually connect to a Team Services project using your enterprise iD?

Comment: As far as I know you need MS account for TFS. That means that the project admin should bind your MS account with the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default way is using Microsoft Account to connect VSTS. But seems you don't have **enough permission** with your MS account on the project. You may need to ask the Project Administrator or the one invited you to give you enough permission.

If you want to login VSTS with your company account.

> ***Sign up for Visual Studio Team Services with a work or school account***
>
> Control access to Visual Studio Team Services the same way you do with
>   Microsoft services like Office 365 and Azure. When you sign up with a
>   work or school account, your Visual Studio Team Services account is
>   connected to your organization's directory (tenant) in [Azure Active
>   Directory (Azure AD).](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-whatis/) You can then use the same username and password
>   as other Microsoft services, like @fabrikam.com. Azure AD helps you
>   enforce policies around accessing your team's critical resources and
>   key assets.

More details, please refer link from MSDN: [Sign up for Visual Studio Team Services: Git & Agile for DevOps, continuous integration, & continuous delivery](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/sign-up-for-visual-studio-team-services#orgaccount)

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the screen to choose between a "work or school account" and a "personal account"? If yes, your email address is both a Microsoft account **and** a work/school account that's managed by Azure. You might be in this situation:

[Q: Why am I asked to choose between a work or school account, and my personal Microsoft account?](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/setup-admin/team-services/sign-up-for-visual-studio-team-services#ChooseOrgAcctMSAcct)

Go to the FAQ under this question:

**Q: Why can't I sign in to my Team Services account after I choose my personal Microsoft account, or my work or school account?**

You'll find steps to sign out completely and try signing in again.